# Any UI library for iOS and Android (Illustrator)?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, interface-design, android, mobile, ios

I'm developing monochromatic Wireframe and the full color demo of my App UI for iOS and Android. I'm using Illustrator. Is there any UI library for me to use? (ex. the default switch, table view, text field, button, etc.)

Comment: Yes. There are a lot of them. Try googling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I found very good one: 
http://www.graphicsfuel.com/2014/09/ios-8-vector-app-ui-kit/

hope it helps everyone ^^